# Can I program/compile OpenGL 4.0 code on my computer without a graphics card or MESA?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4, mesa

I recently began working with Open GL 4.0 using the Redbook 8th edition. From the start of the morning until now I wasn't able to compile the 'HelloWorld' of OpenGL programs.

I configured the dependencies, transferred file contents of freeGlut/GLEW/GLSL to the respective VC folder for my VS 2013 C++ IDE. I eventually became convinced that the catalyst for this breakdown of events happened because VS was referencing multiple lib files in different locations and the linker couldn't make heads- to tails of what it was referencing.

However I realized another issue that I was naive/ignorant about. **Could I be having compiling issues not because of my dependency configuration but because I only have a built in chipset instead of a card and no MESA?**

I don't know if my built-in chipset supports openGL 4.0

*Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000*

EDIT: My compiltation errors within VS 2013 give no 'clue' that its a hardware issue. All of them are LNK2005 issues.

Comment: Considering OpenGL is designed to be extended at ***run-time***, the hardware you are using (or not using, in this case) has nothing to do with how the code is compiled. Any compiler errors are 100% the result of something unrelated...

Comment: According to Intel [here](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm), the 4000 supports OpenGL 4.0. YMMV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *compile* GL4 programs all day long.  Totally independent of what graphics hardware you may or may not have.  Hell, you can cross-compile Win32 OpenGL programs from a headless Linux box using MinGW if you really wanted to!

Whether or not you can *run* those programs is a function of your GL implementation.

[Wiki claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Seventh_generation) you can do [GL 4.0 with your HD 4000 on Windows](http://www.geeks3d.com/20120506/intel-hd-graphics-driver-v2729-with-opengl-4-support-and-new-opengl-extensions/).

Comment: Aye, and with mesa3d you can do software rendering.

Comment: @user1095108: but mesa has not reached GL4 yet

Comment: Put a call to glGetString(GL_VERSION) in your code and see what your GPU returns. For completeness, call glGetString(GL_RENDERER) and glGetString(GL_VENDOR) too. My HD Graphics 5000 supports GL 4.0 but I don't know if the HD Graphics 4000 does.